# AJAX Second call doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a simple voting button but it works only one time per post per reload.

How should it work: 
Click "+" -> update query (in django) -> reload a div (change "+" to "-") -> allow to click "-" to undo the upvote

It shows the "-" button after I vote for the first time but when I click it, nothing happens. It works only if I hit "F5" and reload the page.

There are no errors in console.

```
        ... some django scripts to check which button should be displayed ...

         <span class="upvote"><span postId="{{post.id}}" class="vote" href="upvote/{{post.id}}">+</span></span>

         <span class="downvote"><span postId="{{post.id}}" class="vote" href="downvote/{{post.id}}">-</span></span>
         ...

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".vote").click(function(e){
          href = $(this).attr("href");
          postId = $(this).attr("postId");
          $.ajax({
                url: href,
                success: function() {
                    $("#post-"+postId+" >header").load(location.href+ " #post-"+postId+">header>*");
                },
           });
        });
```

The "postId" and "href" attributes are properly filled

Comment: why not use a <a> tag arround the <span.vote>, with href to page?

Comment: it works well with <a> but the page scrolls to the top every 2nd click. Probably that's the reason I've changed it to <span> so I would like to stick with it if there's a way

Comment: try to put `$(".vote").click() ` handle event outside `$(document).ready()` context.

Comment: still the same, it has changed nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious what the problem is based on the code you posted, but I'm guessing that the `<span>-</span>` is added to the DOM *after* you have click on `<span>+</span>`. If that is the case, then your problem is that you have only bound `$('.vote').on('click'...` to the `.vote` elements that were in the DOM when that code first executed on page load. You can fix this by using event delegation to bind the event handler to a static parent element and act on any events coming from children that match your selector:

```
$(document).on('click', ".vote", function(e){
    href = $(this).attr("href");
    postId = $(this).attr("postId");
    $.ajax({
       url: href,
       success: function() {
          $("#post-"+postId+" >header").load(location.href+ " #post-"+postId+">header>*");
       },
   });
})
```